# Python3-ldap KeyError: 'attributes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

Using Python3.4 with the `python3-ldap` module loaded.  Using the code:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS #For title queires into LDAP

def GetTitle(u):
    print(u)
    t=[]

    server = Server(DomanCtrlr)
    c = Connection(server,
                   auto_bind=AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS,
                   read_only=True,
                   check_names=True,
                   user = user,
                   password= password)

    c.search(search_base = 'dc=corp,dc=weyer,dc=pri',
             search_filter = '(&(samAccountName=' + u + '))',
             search_scope = SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE,
             attributes = ['title'],
             paged_size = 5)

    for entry in c.response:
        print(entry['attributes']['title'])
        t = entry['attributes']['title']
        print(u, " : ", t)

users = ['user1', 'notAuser', 'user2']

for u in users:
    GetTitle(u)
```

I expect to get an error for notAuser, but instead I get this output:

```
user1
['CONTROL ROOM OPERATOR']
user1  :  ['CONTROL ROOM OPERATOR']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olsonma\Documents\ThreatMatrix_PY\LDAPTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    GetTitle(u)
  File "C:\Users\olsonma\Documents\ThreatMatrix_PY\LDAPTest.py", line 17, in GetTitle
    print(entry['attributes']['title'])
KeyError: 'attributes'
```

Since the line obviously executed I am not clear how the error is happening.

I have found a lot of articles for the old `python-ldap` error similar to this, but the option to fix it for python-ldap does not seen to be an option for `python3-ldap`.  Does anyone know 
1.) why this happening?
2.) how to make it stop?

Comment: I just realized that it is attempting a second run through the for loop so I printed the full c.response and found a second entry in the response that does not contain 'attributes' keyword. I believe my fix is to check the length of the response and only process if there are two responses and then to only process the first response item.  Will post fixed code if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prints have been removed from code since I have found the issue.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS #For title queires into LDAP

def GetTitle(u):

    t=''

    server = Server(DomainCtrlr)
    c = Connection(server,
                   auto_bind=AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS,
                   read_only=True,
                   check_names=True,
                   user = user,
                   password= password)

    c.search(search_base = 'dc=corp,dc=weyer,dc=pri',
             search_filter = '(&(samAccountName=' + u + '))',
             search_scope = SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE,
             attributes = ['title'],
             paged_size = 5)

   if len(c.response) > 1:
        for entry in c.response:
            t = entry['attributes']['title']
            return t

users = ['lafrenh', 'userid', 'garlockb']

for u in users:
    title = GetTitle(u)
    print(title)
```